# How to use BugSense correctly with custom data?

Tags: android, bugsense

I try to implement BugSense in my Android Application, but I'm not able to see the custom data I submitted. I really can't find out where the problem is, because I get an error report but without custom data. I implemented com.bugsense.trace.ExceptionCallback to receive all unhandled exceptions in the "lastBreath" method.

Here is my example code:

```
@Override
public void lastBreath(Exception arg0) {
    Log.w(TAG, "executing lastBreath");
    // adding current details to crash data
    HashMap<String, String> errorDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
    errorDetails.put("testKey", "testValue");
    errorDetails.put("testKey2", "testValue2");
    BugSenseHandler.sendExceptionMap(errorDetails, arg0);
    Log.w(TAG, "lastBreath executed");
}
```

This is generating an error report but I don't know where to find the custom values of "testKey" and "testKey2". I used the example code of the official site, so where is the problem? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this data collection a little bit different from you. Here is how I do it:

```
//Call the initAndStartSession right before the setContentView of your activity (onCreate method)
BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(UserLogin.this, APIKEY);
//Add the values that you need to monitor
BugSenseHandler.addCrashExtraData("testKey", testKey);
BugSenseHandler.addCrashExtraData("testKey2", testKey2);
```

Once the error occurs, go to your BugSense errors page. (The link should look something like: https://www.bugsense.com/dashboard/project/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/errors/ ) and click on the exception link (as seen on the image bellow).

[image: Errors Page]

Now, once on the error page, click on the "Error Instances"

[image: Error Instances]

Now, if you click on the wrench Icon, you will see your "testKey" and "testKey2" available to be shown.
[image: Last Step]

Hope it works!